# Maximize Chrome window

Tags: powershell

I am trying to correctly write a script to open a Chrome session maximized.  If Chrome was previously closed and it happened to be set to a smaller window size, when opened again, it will automatically open to the last set window size.

I know the code to open to a specific window size

```
Get-Process chrome | Set-Window -X -8 -Y -1 -Width 1938 -Height 1049
```

However, I cannot figure out how to simply maximize the window.  The only solution "close" to what I want that I have gotten to work is making the window full-screen, which is not the goal.

I have tried something as simple as

```
(Get-Process -ProcessName chrome).UI.RawUI.MaxWindowSize
```

but this does not work.

EDIT to help Joey:

This is the function that powers Set-Window

```
    Function Set-Window {
[OutputType('System.Automation.WindowInfo')]
[cmdletbinding()]
Param (
    [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
    $ProcessName,
    [int]$X,
    [int]$Y,
    [int]$Width,
    [int]$Height,
    [switch]$Passthru
)
Begin {
    Try{
        [void][Window]
    } Catch {
    Add-Type @"
          using System;
          using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
          public class Window {
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

            [DllImport("User32.dll")]
            public extern static bool MoveWindow(IntPtr handle, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool redraw);
          }
          public struct RECT
          {
            public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
            public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
            public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
            public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
          }
"@
        }
    }
    Process {
        $Rectangle = New-Object RECT
        $Handle = (Get-Process -Name $ProcessName).MainWindowHandle
        $Return = [Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle,[ref]$Rectangle)
        If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Width')) {            
            $Width = $Rectangle.Right - $Rectangle.Left            
        }
        If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Height')) {
            $Height = $Rectangle.Bottom - $Rectangle.Top
        }
        If ($Return) {
            $Return = [Window]::MoveWindow($Handle, $x, $y, $Width, $Height,$True)
        }
        If ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Passthru')) {
            $Rectangle = New-Object RECT
            $Return = [Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle,[ref]$Rectangle)
            If ($Return) {
                $Height = $Rectangle.Bottom - $Rectangle.Top
                $Width = $Rectangle.Right - $Rectangle.Left
                $Size = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size -ArgumentList $Width, $Height
                $TopLeft = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates -ArgumentList $Rectangle.Left, $Rectangle.Top
                $BottomRight = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates -ArgumentList $Rectangle.Right, $Rectangle.Bottom
                If ($Rectangle.Top -lt 0 -AND $Rectangle.LEft -lt 0) {
                    Write-Warning "Window is minimized! Coordinates will not be accurate."
                }
                $Object = [pscustomobject]@{
                    ProcessName = $ProcessName
                    Size = $Size
                    TopLeft = $TopLeft
                    BottomRight = $BottomRight
                }
                $Object.PSTypeNames.insert(0,'System.Automation.WindowInfo')
                $Object            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, what about the following change to your function (untested).

```
Function Set-Window {
[OutputType('System.Automation.WindowInfo')]
[cmdletbinding()]
Param (
    [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
    $ProcessName,
    [int]$X,
    [int]$Y,
    [int]$Width,
    [int]$Height,
    [switch]$Maximize,
    [switch]$Passthru
)
Begin {
    Try{
        [void][Window]
    } Catch {
    Add-Type @"
          using System;
          using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
          public class Window {
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

            [DllImport("User32.dll")]
            public extern static bool MoveWindow(IntPtr handle, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool redraw);

            [DllImport("User32.dll")]
            public extern static bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
          }
          public struct RECT
          {
            public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
            public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
            public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
            public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
          }
"@
        }
    }
    Process {
        $Rectangle = New-Object RECT
        $Handle = (Get-Process -Name $ProcessName).MainWindowHandle

        if ($Maximize) {
          [Window]::ShowWindow($Handle, 3)
        }

        $Return = [Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle,[ref]$Rectangle)
        If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Width')) {            
            $Width = $Rectangle.Right - $Rectangle.Left            
        }
        If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Height')) {
            $Height = $Rectangle.Bottom - $Rectangle.Top
        }
        If ($Return) {
            $Return = [Window]::MoveWindow($Handle, $x, $y, $Width, $Height,$True)
        }
        If ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Passthru')) {
            $Rectangle = New-Object RECT
            $Return = [Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle,[ref]$Rectangle)
            If ($Return) {
                $Height = $Rectangle.Bottom - $Rectangle.Top
                $Width = $Rectangle.Right - $Rectangle.Left
                $Size = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size -ArgumentList $Width, $Height
                $TopLeft = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates -ArgumentList $Rectangle.Left, $Rectangle.Top
                $BottomRight = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates -ArgumentList $Rectangle.Right, $Rectangle.Bottom
                If ($Rectangle.Top -lt 0 -AND $Rectangle.LEft -lt 0) {
                    Write-Warning "Window is minimized! Coordinates will not be accurate."
                }
                $Object = [pscustomobject]@{
                    ProcessName = $ProcessName
                    Size = $Size
                    TopLeft = $TopLeft
                    BottomRight = $BottomRight
                }
                $Object.PSTypeNames.insert(0,'System.Automation.WindowInfo')
                $Object            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
Get-Process chrome | Set-Window -Maximize
```

Comment: Joey, I added the function to create Set-Window to the OP.  I understand I can probably base my code off of that, but I haven't figured out how.  "Simple" or not

Comment: It makes sense, but it doesn't do anything.  It just runs and ends.  Not sure if this has something to do with it, but a `Get-Process chrome` pulls up nine different PID's.

Comment: Yeah, only one of them will have any kind of »main window« from Windows' point of view. The rest are the rendering job processes.

Comment: Agreed.  I guess what I have to do is figure out how to get all of the processes to maximize.  The way I have things set up, there is only one Chrome window, albeit it with multiple tabs.  So just maximizing the one window is all that has to be done.

Answer (score 0):

> Start-Process chrome.exe -WindowStyle maximized

Comment: This does not work.  It just opens another window of Chrome with the same window size as the previously opened instance.